# Editing a previously saved document also updates it in the db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

FYI, using Mongodb, Express, and Mongoose on node.js.

I'm saving a document (a user, that contains data) with `.save()`, and then I want to return this user on the request through the `.send()`.
However I certainly do not want to return its password, so I'm accessing the previously saved document and removing the password with the following:

```
user.status = /* Create new status and assign */;
user.save();
user.password = undefined;
```

It should be noted that this is inside a couple of callbacks as such (pseudo-code):

```
Users.findOne (
    // Do stuff
    user.token = /* New token */;
    user.save();

    Shops.findOne( /* search by userId */
        // Do stuff
        user._shopId = shopId;
        user.status = "active";
        user.save();

        // Hide password
        user.password = undefined;

        // Send
        res.send({success: true, user: user});
    )
)
```

I expected the database document for this user to remain the same, since I did not save it after editing it. And yes, if I don't `.save()`, I can change it at will (like using an update to update it and on its callback `.send()`).

However, the document's password gets removed. Is the `.save()` somehow asynchronous, or only runs at the end of the thread's life even though I put it at the middle of its code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the `user.save();` give a callback. Something like this :

```
Users.findOne (
// Do stuff
user.token = /* New token */;
user.save();

Shops.findOne( /* search by userId */
    // Do stuff
    user._shopId = shopId;
    user.status = "active";
    user.save(function(err, user){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        if(user){
            // Hide password
            user.password = undefined;
            res.send({success: true, user: user});
        }
});
));
```

Everything in the callback will be synchronous. So the response will be sent only when the user is saved.

Should be noted that `.save()` uses the object's pointer to save, and doesn't statically send the object through a parameter, therefore changing this object before the `.save()` finishes means it will be changed before it's saved in the database.

Comment: This is the correct answer. However my edit should be noted for future readers.